# How to replace NULL values without updating the table or creating temp table

Tags: mysql

I have a sick day table where the data only show when the employee is sick but there is no input when he/she is healthy.
I am trying to get the full count of all employees, sick or not.
I have the query below and I was able to create a new field (present_cnt) and the only fields populated on each row were the present_cnt=1 and the calendar date and the rest were null.
I don't know how to populate the rest of the fields (for employee 921 and 922) to replace the nulls when they are not sick. I don't have access to update the table or create a temp table. I only need the result of the query to populate the null values for each employees.
Thanks!

```
SELECT
employeeId,
sick_date,
sick_cnt,
CASE WHEN calendar_date = sick_date THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS present_cnt,
calendar_date

FROM
sick_day_table
```

This is the result I have:

```
employeeId  sick_date   sick_cnt    present_cnt calendar_date
921         4/29/2020 0:00  1              0    4/29/2020 0:00
921         4/30/2020 0:00  1              0    4/30/2020 0:00
NULL        NULL          NULL             1    5/1/2020 0:00
NULL        NULL          NULL             1    5/2/2020 0:00
922         4/29/2020 0:00  1              0    4/29/2020 0:00
NULL        NULL          NULL             1    4/30/2020 0:00
NULL        NULL          NULL             1    5/1/2020 0:00
NULL        NULL          NULL             1    5/2/2020 0:00
```

Desire result:

```
employeeId  sick_date   sick_cnt    present_cnt calendar_date
921         4/29/2020 0:00  1              0    4/29/2020 0:00
921         4/30/2020 0:00  1              0    4/30/2020 0:00
921         5/1/2020 0:00   0              1    5/1/2020 0:00
921         5/2/2020 0:00   0              1    5/2/2020 0:00
922         4/29/2020 0:00  1              0    4/29/2020 0:00
922         4/30/2020 0:00  0              1    4/30/2020 0:00
922         5/1/2020 0:00   0              1    5/1/2020 0:00
922         5/2/2020 0:00   0              1    5/2/2020 0:00
```

Comment: Provide source table with some sample data (i.e. CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO). Show desired output for this data. Specify MySQL version precisely.

Comment: If the `employeeId` is `NULL`, how do you know what value is supposed to be there?  How was it set to `NULL` in the first place?

Comment: Hi @RocketHazmat, there was only calendar date field populated fro each day in a year in the first place and the rest are nulls, then I added the present_cnt column. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @user3647971, yes correct! The only thing left is how can I populate the employeeId column.

Comment: You almost have it with CASE WHEN: `SELECT employeeId, CASE WHEN sick_date IS NULL THEN calendar_date ELSE sick_date END AS sick_date,  CASE WHEN sick_cnt IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE sick_cnt END AS sick_cnt, CASE WHEN calendar_date = sick_date THEN 0 ELSE 1  END AS present_cnt, calendar_date FROM sick_day_table`